Casting an equation to float in C?
buffer[0] = ((float)(( buffer[0] + buffer[1])/3)+0.8);

int buffer[100];

I haven’t been able to find a satisfactory answer yet, and I can’t run this code at the moment to test.
I’ve inherited an embedded C code base with equations like above where an individual just casts the whole equation to a float.
I understand integer math and if you are doing something like division with integers then at least one needs to be casted to a float  to get an accurate answer instead of a truncated answer. But I’ve never seen casting an entire equation to a float.
My questions are:

Will this result in the compiler treating everything as a float?

Does the equation in parentheses get done first and then the result casted to a float? In that latter case,


(buffer[0] + buffer[1])/3)

would be integer division and the decimal truncated before being promoted to a double for the addition to 0.8.
Any ideas?

The addition and division will be done with integer arithmetic. Then that will be converted to float before adding 0.8. Finally, that result will be converted back to int when assigning to buffer[0].

So the answers are 1. No, 2. Yes.

BTW, it's generally best to forget that the float type exists. Use double when possible, and it's what the default promotions do.

The cast in your inherited code is useless. The division is still integer division, whose result is cast to float, which is unnecesarily too late, because the next + 0.8 will perform double arithmetic anyways, and then the 0.8 will still be lost (if positive) by truncating to integer. You can't add 0.8 to a positive integer and get a different integer (even if it has been cast to float). You should try to understand the author's intentions: what where they trying to do?

The fact that it's embedded is irrelevant. The rules of C math are the same for all architectures.

@WeatherVane I suspect that's what they need to fix. The original author mistakenly thought #1, but it's actually #2.

Perhaps buffer[0] = (buffer[0] + buffer[1]) / 3.0 + 0.8; but IDK the author's intention. This may still generate a compiler warning about loss of significance.

@Barmar it will be converted to double because on almost all current C/C++ compilers that is the default type of an unqualified value like +0.8. If you wanted it converted to float then +0.8f will have that effect (odd choice of additive constant did they mean 0.5). It looks to me like the random laying on of casts until the code is accepted by the compiler. If you can be sure overflow will not occur then it could be done in pure integer arithmetic  ( 5*(b[0]+b[1]/3)+4)/5 which at least on prehistoric CPUs would be very much faster. Today much less difference.

@MartinBrown I know. That's what I meant when I wrote "that's what the default promotions do". For the OP's needs, I think the distinction between float and double is irrelevant, they just need floating point.

Thanks Barmar and Weather Vane for essentially confirming what was my understanding (#2 above). Thought I was going crazy. Agree that the rules of C are same for all architectures. This is an embedded code base that has been touched by multiple people over 10+ years, and primarily electrical/hardware engineers. So most likely answer is they just didn’t fully understand the rules of how math works in C. Will have to correct  the code. Thanks!

Terminology note: you're not casting an equation. You're casting the result of (part of) some arithmetic code.

Another point for embedded code is that using float at all results in a hell of  a lot of additional FP library baggage added to the ROM footprint on older CPUs and compiler/inkers. We went great lengths to avoid that using scaled integer fixed point code and/or correctly rounded integer arithmetic. muldiv(x,y,z) was very handy for that since hardware support was usually OK but language support for it often wasn't.

@MartinBrown: of course, it depends on the embedded target. One can still find very modern embedded CPUs and compilers which have zero hardware FP support (because it occupies valuable die area & consumes extra power), for which any FP operations involve linking very slow & large software FP libraries. If FP usage is unavoidable, we would still prefer float over double as the efficiency savings can be significant, especially on small micros where the word size is 8- or 16-bits.

@MartinBrown Yes for older processors but nowadays with many processors having FPUs it doesn't matter. Using an STM32 that has a double precision FPU.



Will this result in the compiler treating everything as a float?


No. A cast says to convert the value of the operand to the cast type. It does not affect evaluation inside the operand.


Does the equation in parentheses get done first and then the result casted to a float?


There is an expression inside the parentheses, not an equation. (See below.)
C evaluates the parts of an expression independently, without consideration for the expression they are contained in, and it evaluates the subexpressions independently, and so on. (There are limited exceptions, such as sizeof expression merely analyzes expression to determine its type; it is not evaluated.)
In buffer[0] = ((float)(( buffer[0] + buffer[1])/3)+0.8):

For buffer[0] + buffer[1], buffer[0] and buffer[1] are added. (Depending on their values, this could overflow, and the behavior would not be defined by the C standard.)
For ( buffer[0] + buffer[1])/3, the sum is divided by 3 using int arithmetic, which truncates fractions, thus rounding results toward 0.
For (float)(( buffer[0] + buffer[1])/3), the result of the division is converted to float. This can also overflow and have undefined behavior.
For (float)(( buffer[0] + buffer[1])/3)+0.8, 0.8 is added to the float resulting from the previous step.
Finally, the result of the addition is converted to int (which truncates toward zero) and assigned to buffer[0]. (The conversion to int is because the target of the assignment, buffer[0], has that type.)

Supplement
An equation is an assertion that two expressions have the same value. y = x2 is an equation. x2 is not an equation. It is an expression.
This code is almost certainly wrong, because the result of the int division is an integer, and therefore adding 0.8 immediately before the assignment will not change a nonnegative result. For example, if the division produces 5, the conversion to float will also produce 5 (as a float), and then the implicit conversion to double will produce 5, and the addition of 0.8 will produce (approximately) 5.8. Then the conversion to int for assignment to buffer[0] will produce 5. So it will be as if the 0.8 were not added.
If the division produces a negative value, the addition will change it. For example, if the division produces −5, the conversion to float and then double will also produce −5, and then the addition of 0.8 will produce (approximately) −4.2. Then the conversion to int will produce −4. So, it is hypothetically possible the author added 0.8 because they wanted to add one to a negative quotient but keep nonnegative quotients unchanged. But I would have done that by adding a simpler constant, say 0.5, and clearly documenting its purpose.
Even if the code were intended to do this, the conversion to float appears is unnecessary. For the expression with + 0.8, the left operand would be automatically converted to double. For integer values that do not overflow float, converting to float and then double produces the same result as converting to double. This is a further sign this code is poorly written.

In addition to various concerns addressed by other answers:
Another issue - float versus double math.

I understand integer math and if you are doing something like division with integers then at least one needs to be casted to a float to get an accurate answer

Casting an int to float may lose precision.
To get an accurate answer, cast to a floating point type that is at least as precise as the integer type.
Consider the difference of casting to float versus double:
int main(void) {
  for (int i = INT_MAX; i > 0; i--) {
    int y0 = ((float) i / 3) + 0.8;
    int y1 = ((double) i / 3) + 0.8;
    if (y0 != y1) {
      printf("%d %d %d\n", i, y0, y1);
      break;
    }
  }
}

Output
2147483647 715827904 715827883


Truncate vs. round
Instead of truncating, often it is better to round.  Use lround() to round and convert a FP to an integer in one step.
//buffer[0] = ((float)(( buffer[0] + buffer[1])/3)+0.8);
buffer[0] = lround( ((double)buffer[0] + buffer[1])/3) + 0.8 );

Consider a step further: sum with wider integer math to avoid overflow.
#if LLONG_MAX > INT_MAX
  buffer[0] = lround( ((long long)buffer[0] + buffer[1])/3.0) + 0.8 );


Could stay with integer math
/3 and + 0.8 can be done with scaled integer math.
#if LLONG_MAX > INT_MAX
  long long sum = (long long)buffer[0] + buffer[1];
  long long sum30 = sum * 10 + 24; // Scale by 30;
  buffer[0] = sum30/30;  // Truncate
  //  
  buffer[0] = sum30/30 + (sum30%30 >= 15);  // Round

Given that 0.8 does not form a double with the exact value of eights-tenths, sticking with integer math will result in a more accurate result in edge cases.
Additional review needed depending on how one might want to round, especially with negative buffer[].
